# Div is not moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, positioning

I am trying to move `div`'s position but it is not moving. Any idea?

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#box").attr("left","300px");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
      $("#box").css("position", "relative");
      $("#box").css("left","300px");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

simple answer: `$('#box').css({'left' : '300px'});`
*Also make sure your `position` is set to either `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`.*

Answer (score 0):

The `div` is probably `position: static`.

It needs to be one of

- `position: relative`
- `position: absolute`
- `position: fixed`

for `left` to have any effect.